# Scripts and Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, sysbench

I am trying to run a mysql benchmark (sysbench) inside my docker container. The script works well and performs the benchmark while running in the host terminal but when I try to run it inside a container I get an error as:

> FATAL: unable to connect to MySQL server, aborting... FATAL: error
>   2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) ALERT: Error: failed to determine
>   table 'sbtest' type! ALERT: MySQL error: Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) FATAL: failed
>   to get database capabilities!

---

My docker file is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y sysbench

ADD ./script.sh /code/script.sh

WORKDIR /code

ENTRYPOINT ./script.sh
```

And my script is:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'

sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server 

sudo mysql --user="root" --password="root" -e "create database dbtest"

sudo sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=dbtest --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=root prepare

sudo sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=1000000 --oltp-test-mode=complex --oltp-read-only=off --num-threads=6 --max-time=60 --max-requests=0 --mysql-db=dbtest --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=root run
```

How can I fix this, because the same script works on a normal Linux machine?

Comment: What are the contents of `entrypoint.sh`?

Comment: what is your `docker build` command, and where are you running it from?

Comment: is entrypoint.sh executable?

Comment: Can you add some formatting to your question, particularly to make the script more readable?  Can you include any output that you get from trying to run the container?

Comment: The error message is already mentioned in  the question. Their is a problem in connecting with the locally installed mysql

Comment: why not use official mysql docker image  as base?

Comment: Because I am doing benchmarking of containers with respect to VMs. So maintaining the system software specifications